# Parse conf file to a tree PHP

Tags: php

I would like to use PHP to turn the following array to a printed output as such.

```
Array

(

    [relation] => Array

        (

            [parent.item] => Array

                (

                    [0] => p0

                    [1] => p1

                )



            [p0.item] => Array

                (

                    [0] => business

                    [1] => tourism

                )

            [business.item] => Array

                (

                    [0] => X

                    [1] => Y

                )


        )
```

To

```
0 p0
  + business
    - 0 X
    - 1 Y
```

This is a piece of code I found and edited to my needs so far, but i can't wrap my head around how to do it...

```
function plotTree($arr, $indent=0, $mother_run=true){

if ($mother_run) {

    // the beginning of plotTree. We're at rootlevel

    echo "start\n";

}

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value){

    // show the indents

    echo str_repeat("  ", $indent);

    if ($indent == 0) {

        // this is a root node. no parents

        echo "O ";

    } elseif (is_array($value)){

        // this is a normal node. parents and children

        echo "+ ";

    } else {

        // this is a leaf node. no children

        echo "- ";

    }

    // show the actual node

    echo $key . " (" . $value. ")" . "\n";

    if (is_array($value)) {

        // this is what makes it recursive, rerun for childs

        plotTree($value, ($indent+1), false);

    }

}

if ($mother_run) {

    echo "end\n";

}

}

// Parse with sections

$ini_array = parse_ini_file("test.ini", true);

file_put_contents('test.txt', print_r($ini_array,true));

plotTree($ini_array['relation']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this...

```
<?php

    $sampleArray = array();

    $sampleArray["relation"]["parent.item"] = array("p0", "p1");
    $sampleArray["relation"]["p0.item"] = array("business", "tourism");
    $sampleArray["relation"]["business.item"] = array("x", "y");

    $value2 = $sampleArray["relation"]["parent.item"];
    foreach($value2 as $key3=>$value3){
        echo "$key3 $value3<br>";
        $types = $sampleArray["relation"][$value3.".item"];
        foreach($types as $type){
            echo " + $type<br>";
            $items = $sampleArray["relation"][$type.".item"];
            foreach($items as $index=>$item){
                echo " - $index $item<br>";
            }

            echo "<p>";
        }
    }
?>
```